# Checking a checkbox to submit to a link not working in Chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a link in a razor view (.NET MVC3) which is part of a sort function which shows all records (active and archived) or the active ones (the default on page load). It works fine in Firefox. But it only works when I click on the text part of the link not when the checkbox is checked for chrome and IE. Here is the code I've used.

```
        <a id="lnkShowAll" href="@Url.Action("showAll", "myController", new { showOnlyActive = !Model.Active })" >
        <input id="chkShowAll" type="checkbox"  
                @if(!Model.Active){
                    @: checked="checked"
                } >
          Show All (<span class="activeFont">Active</span> / <span class="archivedFont">Archived</span> )
        </a>
```

This is the Controller but I doubt the problem is with the controller since no call is being made to it when the check box is checked

```
public ActionResult Index(bool showOnlyActive = true)
    {
        RecordList recordList = searchForRecordList(showOnlyActive);
        return View("Index", recordList) ;
    }
```

Does anyone have any Idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not sure why it works in firefox but not in Chrome and IE, but I found a solution that works for all.
I wrote an event for the click function of the link in jquery.

```
        $("#lnkShowAll").click(function(event)
        {
          var link = $(this);
          var target = link.attr("target");

          if($.trim(target).length > 0)
          {
            window.open(link.attr("href"), target);
          }
          else
          {
             window.location = link.attr("href");
          }

          event.preventDefault();
        });
```

And added a click function to trigger a click event of the link when the checkbox is checked/unchecked.

```
$("#chkShowAll").click(function(){
            $("#lnkShowAll").click();
});
```

This ensures that the link is clicked whenever the checkbox is clicked on no matter what browser you are using.